# Proofing that $rk(A) \leq r$

Tags: matrices

So I have to proof that for an element $A$ of $M_{m\times n}(K)$ r an  element of $N$, $rk(A)\leq r$ if there are two matrices $B$ element of  $M_{m\times r}(K)$ and $C$ element of  $M_{r\times n}(K)$ with $A=BC.$

I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Comment: Does the term "Singular Value decomposition" mean something to you? With that property, it is very easy to see. But since it is advances Matrix stuff, answering this question based upon it, may be an overkill and not helpful at all.

Comment: no...  I unfortunately never heard of it